# Wrong convert Object from JSON

Tags: java, json, object, gson

First, sorry for my poor English.

Second, my problem.
I trying convert to JSON and back this structure:

```
class Revision{
    private String auth;
    private HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> rev;

    public String getAuth(){
        return auth;
}

    public HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> getRev(){
        return rev;
}

    public void setAuth(String auth){
        this.auth = auth;
}

    public void setRev(HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> rev){
        this.rev = (HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>>) rev.clone();
}

    public String toString(){
        return "Auth: " + auth + ", rev: " + rev;
}
}
```

I do it with this code:

```
public static void main (String[] argc){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Revision revision = new Revision();

    HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> HM = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>>();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> HMin = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    HMin.put("id", 12);
    HMin.put("type", "toster");
    list.add(HMin);
    HM.put("mark", list);

    revision.setRev(HM);
    revision.setAuth("ololo");

    String json = gson.toJson(revision);

    Revision test = new Gson().fromJson(json, Revision.class);

    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(revision);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

In finally I get this result:

```
{"auth":"ololo","rev":{"mark":[{"id":12,"type":"toster"}]}}
Auth: ololo, rev: {mark=[{id=12, type=toster}]}
Auth: ololo, rev: {mark=[{id=java.lang.Object@1c672d0, type=java.lang.Object@19bd03e}]}
```

As you can see, after convertation, Object-type parameters incorrect.
Please, can you tell me, how I can fix this trouble?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think so.
I try do this:  

HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> HMout = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>>();
HMout = (HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>>) test.getRev().clone();    System.out.println(((HMout.get("mark")).get(0)).get("id").toString());
And i get **java.lang.Object@1c672d0** as result =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out and see if it is working? Yeah, I know you want to support `Object` type, but this is just for try sake.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Revision revision = new Revision();

HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> HM = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> HMin = new HashMap<String, String>();

HMin.put("id", "12");
HMin.put("type", "toster");
list.add(HMin);
HM.put("mark", list);

revision.setRev(HM);
revision.setAuth("ololo");

String json = gson.toJson(revision);

Revision test = new Gson().fromJson(json, Revision.class);

System.out.println(json);
System.out.println(revision);
System.out.println(test);
```

**[Edited]**

Now try this snippet directly, with a respective change in `Revision` class.

```
Revision test = new Gson().fromJson("{\"auth\":\"ololo\",\"rev\":{\"mark\":[{\"id\":12,\"type\":13}]}}", Revision.class);
System.out.println(test);
```

Change this in `Revision` class to this,

```
HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Integer>>> HM = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Integer>>>();
```

This is to make sure that its working good with specific type. If it does, we will be sure that it can't work with `Obejct` type somehow. Then you can file a bug there, for their good. And for the time being you can switch to some other API, if you like to. You can find few options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

Comment: I try do this, but I have error here **revision.setRev(HM);**
If I change Object to String in Revision-type you code work!

Comment: @user473032: Check my addendum.

Comment: Adeel Ansari: Yes, it's working correctly.  I'll try find another API from your link. Thanks for help!